# ¿como poner inicio dual ubuntu si mi computador arranca por windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows10, grub2

Esta pregunta es distinta, o al menos eso creo, de las demás que he visto.
Resulta que instalé bien ubuntu (reitero, instalé bien, seguí correctamente absolutamente todos los pasos) 18.04 desde mi usb en mi computador, que tiene windows 10. El problema es, que a pesar de que ubuntu está instalado y se guardan cosas y todo en esa partición, cuando inicio el computador, éste arranca directamente por windows 10 sin preguntar en el grub.
Para poder abrir mi grub tengo que poner la usb, donde aparece la grub del usb live, donde dice "-try ubuntu,-install ubuntu, ...etc". en esta pantalla no clickeo ninguna sino que doy tecla Esc, luego escribo en un tipo de terminal que aparece como "grub>" el comando "exit" y ahí recién me muestra el menú de boot (al que podría acceder con F9). Ahí lo que hago es seleccionar "TOSHIBA....." y ahí si puedo arrancar ubuntu, el que tengo instalado.
Lo que quiero es que ese grub me aparesca simplemente cuando el computador se enciende, osea de forma normal, para que me deje decidir el sistema operativo que quiero usar.
He revisado ya varios tutoriales, que dicen: "recuperar grub", "recuperar inicio ubuntu", "recuperar dual boot", etc. Y ninguno de estos me sirve.
Pongo anexo algunos de estos links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xShSp8gPjFE&t=450s&list=PLum-Jn1gEsLzmip-2eHcTevH-lugyHjP9&index=3

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0GebYbmAY0&t=490s&list=PLum-Jn1gEsLzmip-2eHcTevH-lugyHjP9&index=6

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqxMpsMd9T8&t=51s&list=PLum-Jn1gEsLzmip-2eHcTevH-lugyHjP9&index=7

Muchas gracias

Comment: me temo terminará cerrada tu pregunta, revisa sobre que puedes preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic la comunidad es para resolver dudas concretas de programación

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es un tema relacionado con programación

Comment: Te agradecería me dieras referencias de posts o foros en donde bucar, porque la verdad necesito ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ver si tienes instalado el grub (aunque creo que no es tu caso ya que por defecto te lo pone como primera opción) entrando en la bios de tu pc y viendo las opciones de arranque, en la primera opción debes poner el grub, si no es así puedes instalar el grub de arranque desde tu Linux y configurarlo en la bios como te dije anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de incidencias no siempre tienen que ver con la configuración del GRUB, probablemente sea la configuración de tu BIOS (Legacy o UEFI): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50691_01/html/E50101/gnchj.html

Primero tienes que identificar en qué modo está tu BIOS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un video que compara las 2 formas de instalarlo, tanto con UEFI como con Legacy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yEPq2WdjYg

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: por favor revisa en los comentarios, donde ya se le hizo saber al OP que este tipo de preguntas no son para este sitio por que aqui se resuelven dudas de programación por lo tanto es off topic, [answer] [tour]

Comment: aqui esta el enlace donde puedes ver sobre lo que aqui se puede preguntar y por ende responder https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  por otro lado me causa mucha curiosidad por que darle el link de documentación de servidores Oracle? si el OP meciona además que es una pc personal